# Binance futures cant do sl/tp order or Order would immediately trigger

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client, python-binance

When I'm trying to place an order on Binance exchange using `python-binance` library, I'm getting errors like `APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger.` What am I doing wrong? So my logic is open position with limit order like this:

```py
async def place_limit_order(
        self, api_key, api_secret, symbol, quantity, price, side
    ):
        try:
            client = AsyncClient(api_key=api_key, api_secret=api_secret, testnet=True)

            order_params = {
                "symbol": symbol,
                "side": side,
                "type": "LIMIT",
                "timeInForce": "GTC",
                "positionSide": "LONG",
                "quantity": quantity,
                "price": price,
                # "reduceOnly": True,
            }

            # Place limit order 
            order = await client.futures_create_order(**order_params)
            print(f"Limit order placed successfully: {order}")

            return order
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to place limit order: {e}")
            return None
        finally:
            await client.close_connection()
```

Then, when order is placed on exchange, I'm watching user data stream. Then, I'm trying place tp/sl order like this:

```py
    async def place_tp_order(
        self,
        api_key,
        api_secret,
        symbol,
        quantity,
        entry_price,
        stop_price,
        testnet=True,
    ):
        client = await AsyncClient.create(api_key, api_secret, testnet=testnet)

        try:
            order = await client.futures_create_order(
                symbol=symbol,
                side="BUY",
                type="TAKE_PROFIT",
                positionSide="LONG",
                timeInForce="GTC",
                quantity=quantity,
                price=entry_price,
                stopPrice=stop_price,
                # reduceOnly=True,
            )

            print("Take profit placed:")
            print(order)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error place Take profit order: {e}")

        finally:
            await client.close_connection()
```

So what about prices calculation?
I take open price for a candle, for example is `price = 2319` and calculate price like for tp order `stop_price = price + (price) * 0.1`, its up price for one percent and for stop loss order I'm doing the same but on the opposite side. So my orders price look like this: `price=2319, take_profit_price=2342.19, stop_loss_price=2295.81`. But it's giving me errors like `APIError(code=-2021): Order would immediately trigger.` When I'm up my percentage its give me same error.